# Θ, O and Ω, and how they relate to each other as subsets

Tags: algorithm-analysis, asymptotics, runtime-analysis, discrete-mathematics, big-o-notation

I am trying to understand how $\Theta(n)$, $O(n)$,  and $\Omega(n)$ relate to each other as sets and want to make sure I'm on the right track.

I get that $Θ(n) \subseteq O(n)$ since $Θ(n)$ is stronger and all of its elements are also in $O(n)$.

Then $Θ(n) ⊆ Ω(n)$ is true too, yes?

But $O(n) \subseteq Ω(n)$ isn't true?

If I were to make statements that involve the union of two sets I could say:

$Θ(n) ∪ Ω(n) ⊆ O(n)$ is **not** true.

and

$Θ(n) ∪ Ω(n) ⊆ Θ(n)$ is true. For this one, if I am correct, is it still true for a proper subset $(⊂)$?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between Big O, Omega, and Theta?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/129595/what-is-the-difference-between-big-o-omega-and-theta)

Comment: No, and I'm starting to think it's the notation that's confusing me. When the class was given the worksheet similar problems were presented like Θ(n) + Ω(n) = Θ(n), then when nobody could get the correct answers we were told the statement implies Θ(n) ∪ Ω(n) ⊆ Θ(n) and to think of it that way. Now I'm having to pick the true one out of a collection of false ones and yeah, it's just not clicking for me.

Comment: $O$ is an upper bound, $\Omega$ a lower bound, and $\Theta$ is both.

Answer (score 1):

Holds
$$\Theta=O \cap \Omega$$

Answer (score 1):

For two real numbers $a$ and $b$, either $a < b$, $a=b$, or $a>b$.  This notation works analogously but orders functions by growth rates. For two functions of $n$, $f(n)$ and $g(n)$, either $f(n)$ grows slower than $g(n)$, $f(n)$ grows as fast as $g(n)$ or $f(n)$ grows faster than $g(n)$. So if $f$ and $g$ are their grow rates, either $f < g$, $f=g$, or $f > g$.

If $f < g$ or $f = g$ (i.e $f \leq g$) we say $f(n) \in O(g(n))$, if $f > g$ or $f = g$ (i.e $f \geq g$) we say $f(n) \in \Omega(g(n))$, and if $f = g$ we say $f(n) \in \Theta(g(n))$. With real numbers, if $ a \leq b$ and $a \geq b$ then $a=b$ and for the same reason $O(f(n)) \cap \Omega(f(n)) = \Theta(f(n))$.

Here is a Venn diagram of the three sets:

[image]

$\omega(g(n))$ and $o(g(n))$ are subsets of $\Omega(g(n))$ and $O(g(n))$ respectively and contains all functions growing strictly faster or slower ($f > g$ or $f < g$) than $g(n)$.

Answer (score 0):

### Asymptotic Notations

We can [define](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-046j-introduction-to-algorithms-sma-5503-fall-2005/video-lectures/lecture-2-asymptotic-notation-recurrences-substitution-master-method/lec2.pdf) **Asymptotic Notations** in terms of **Set**

For Example,

> $O(g(n))$ = $\{f(n) : \exists$ constants $b>0$ and $n_o>0$ such that $0\leqslant f(n) \leqslant b.g(n) \; \forall \; n\geqslant n_o \}$

It means that $O(g(n))$ is set of all functions $f(n)$ such that there exists positive constants $b$ and $n_o$ such that $0\leqslant f(n) \leqslant b.g(n)$ for all  $n\geqslant n_o$

**Similarly**

> $\Omega(g(n))$ = $\{f(n) : \exists$ constants $a>0$ and $n_o>0$ such that $0\leqslant a.g(n) \leqslant f(n) \; \forall \; n\geqslant n_o \}$

**Now,**

> $\Theta(g(n))$ = $\{f(n) : \exists$ constants $a>0$, $b>0$, and $n_o>0$ such that $0\leqslant a.g(n) \leqslant f(n) \leqslant b.g(n) \; \forall \; n\geqslant n_o \}$

Let's *break* this definition

> $\Theta(g(n))$ = $\{f(n) : \exists$ constants $a>0$, $b>0$, and $n_o>0$ such that $0\leqslant a.g(n) \leqslant f(n)$ **AND**   $0\leqslant f(n) \leqslant b.g(n) \; \forall  \;n\geqslant n_o \}$

*Breaking Further*

> $\Theta(g(n))$ = $\{f(n) : \exists$ constants $a>0$ and $n_o>0$ such that $0\leqslant a.g(n) \leqslant f(n)$ **AND** $\exists$ constant $b>0$ such that  $0\leqslant f(n) \leqslant b.g(n) \; \forall  \;n\geqslant n_o \}$

Now, **AND** is necessarily **INTERSECTION of SETS**. Using, this fact and further modification of definition. We can write.

> $\Theta(g(n))$ = $\{f(n) : \exists$ constants $a>0$ and $n_o>0$ such that $0\leqslant a.g(n) \leqslant f(n) \; \forall \; n\geqslant n_o \}$
> $$\cap$$
> $\;\qquad\qquad\{f(n) : \exists$ constants $b>0$ and $n_o>0$ such that $0\leqslant f(n) \leqslant b.g(n) \; \forall \; n\geqslant n_o \}$

**Thus,**

> $\Theta(g(n)) = \Omega(g(n)) \; \cap \; O(g(n))$

### Now, Question

The notation $\Theta(n), \Omega(n) \text{ and } O(n)$ is specific for one class of functions only namely $g(n)=n$, while the notation used in entire solution till text is general for any function $g(n).$ **Now**,
$$\Theta(n) = \Omega(n) \; \cap \; O(n)$$
**Thus,** using [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2417258) property, we can conclude that
$$\Theta(n) \subseteq O(n)$$
$$\Theta(n) \subseteq \Omega(n)$$***Undoubtedly,*** $O(n) \subseteq \Omega(n)$ **isn't true**. Informally, $O(n)$ contains all *functions $(f(n))$ asymptotically less than or **equal** to $b.n$ (where b is a positive constant)*, **whereas** $\Omega(n)$ contains all *functions $(f(n))$ asymptotically greater than or **equal** to $a.n$ (where a is a positive constant)*. Both are not mutually disjoint, courtesy to ***equal*** in definition. But, definitely one is not subset of other.

**Moreover**. $\Theta(n) \cup \Omega(n) \subseteq O(n)$ **isn't true**. Since $O(n)$ **doesn't** contain functions greater than $n$, while $\Omega(n)$ consists such functions.

**Now,** $\Theta(n) \cup \Omega(n) \subseteq \Theta(n)$ is **definitely NOT true** since, $\Theta(n) \subseteq \Omega(n)$

The following example may **clarify** things

- $\Omega(n)=\{n, n\log n, n^2, n^2\log n, n^3, 2^n, 3^n, n! \;, n^n......\}$
- $O(n)=\{1, \log n, n^{\frac{1}{3}} ,\sqrt n, n, ......\}$

Thus,

- $\Theta(n)=\{n,......\}$

**EDIT**
Fundamental Mistake was corrected in later part of solution, thanks to [Nathaniel](https://cs.stackexchange.com/users/79440/nathaniel)

Comment: You switched the definitions for $O$ and $\Omega$ in the second part of your post. $O(f)$ denotes the set of functions that grow **slower** than $f$ and $\Omega(f)$ describes the set of functions that grow **faster** than $f$. See [there](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) for details.

Comment: $O(n)$ contains all functions asymptotically **less than or equal** to $n$ (by a multiplicative constant). $\Omega(n)$ contains all functions asymptotically **greater than or equal** to $n$ (by a multiplicative constant). So for example, $n\log n \in \Omega(n)$, but $n\log n \notin O(n)$.

Comment: The mistake has been corrected @Nathaniel. Thanks for pointing and explaining it.