# What is the BigO of a C# function when runtime is 3n - logn + 1

Tags: algorithms, big-o-notation, notation

I am trying to learn notations for a course and I am stuck on how to even start. I need to figure out the BigO for this function. Question is there's a C# function bool isPalindrome(string S) which runtime is 3n - logn + 1 milliseconds, where n is the length of the string S.

Please help!

Comment: What is the definition of Big O ?

Comment: This question is pretty Straightforward. Please check [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/148598/143377) answer for definition of Big-$\mathbb{O}$ notation. Please describe what you have tried, and then edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

A general rule of thumb when expressing a function in big O notation is to discard the lower order terms, and to discard the coefficient in the dominant term. For large n, 3n dominates 3n-log n +1, and discarding the coefficient 3 as well, we get that 3n-log n +1=O(n).

There is a formal mathematical definition for big O notation and it can be proved mathematically that 3n-log n+1=O(n).